# ASP.Net MVC application azure active directory Authentication issue "we couldnt signin you, please try again later"

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have implemented Azure Active Directory authentication in my asp.net web app.

startup.auth.cs

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

```
    {

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions

            {

                ClientId = clientId,

                Authority = Authority,

                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,

                RedirectUri = redirectUri,




                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()

                {

                    //

                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.

                    //

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,

                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed

                }

            });
}
```

when i hit application url , its going to AD authentication, when i enter my credentials after completing two factor authentication it keeps trying to connect and finally says "we couldnt signin you, please try again later". please help

[Authentication issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF5Et.png)

its single page application created in asp.net mvc with type script.

please help me to resolve this issue. thanks!!!

Comment: Have you verified with different browsers? and please check if any firewall/VPN is enabled. Refer the process [document and GitHub Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp)

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity. thanks for your reply.  i tried in different browser as well incognito mode as well... there is no firewall enabled. i have followed the same link.. i am not sure if i am missing any other configurations

Comment: Did you tried GitHub sample provided in the link updating your clientId/Applicationid, redirectUrl. and tried to login with the credentials? to find out whether the issue with the application or with the credentials

Comment: Hi @PMC Karur are you still looking for any help on this?

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity : yeah... i could resolve it by following the Github sample. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moving from Comments to answer)

The above issue is resolved by following in the [Document and GitHub Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp).